# Swift conditional downcast does nothing

Tags: swift

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
        if let location = locations.last as? CLLocation {
            //got warning Conditional downcast from CLLocation? to CLLocation does nothing
        }
}
```

In the code above, my understanding is that since locations.last could be nil, so i want to unwrap it carefully. I thought the above code make sense to me but there is a warning "Conditional downcast from CLLocation? to CLLocation does nothing". What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to cast your last location object to `CLLocation` as it is already `CLLocation`.

So you can check whether your last location is nil or not like this.

```
  if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        // you can use lastLocation
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `last` is already an optional computed property.
If you want be sure that isn't nil just use safe unwrap via `if let` or `guard let` construction.

Information about `last` -> [Developer Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689973-last)

Also I write detailed article with examples [My Medium Article](https://medium.com/@vialyx/swift-course-optional-chaining-force-unwrapping-dd1919fe88de)

e.g.

```
if let lastLocation = locations.last {
    print(lastLocation)
    // TODO: - work with lastLocation instance
}
```

or

```
guard let lastLocation = locations.last else {
    return
}
print(lastLocation)
// TODO: - work with lastLocation instance
```